# What is this notification icon with a person's head and a share icon?

Tags: notification-bar, notification-icons

I'm just wondering if anyone knows, what application this icon goes with. It was a screenshot from someone else's phone, so I can't just pull down the status bar and check.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is not an app icon, this is an Android built-in function for sharing content over Bluetooth, Wi-Fi direct, NFC, on Social medias, etc. Also called Direct Share on Marshmallow.